# BufferedWriter close() cause block?

Tags: java, android

code like below

```
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try 
    {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        for(Student stu: ts) {
            bw.write(stu.toString());
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("print something");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("fail...");
    }
```

it seem that BufferedWriter close()  cause block,and

> System.out.println("print something");

is invalid,can't print anything.Why？？

Comment: Is it possible because you are closing the `System.out` stream with `bw.close()` and then trying to do a `System.out.println`

Comment: @immibis  what you mean?

Comment: He means ... what do you mean by "invalid".  You are using a word that does not make sense in that context.

Comment: @StephenC I mean System.out can't print anything

Comment: In that case Phoenix's comment is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the docs of [`BufferedWriter#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close--):

> Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed, further `write()` or `flush()` invocations will cause an `IOException` to be thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

You're closing `System.out` stream and then trying to `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also close the OutputStreamWriter you create to release System.out. You create it inline without naming an object and it is never closed.

```
 OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
 bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
 -----
 The later:

 bw.close();
 osw.close();
```

Also consider closing in *finally* block of the try-catch

Comment: That wouldn't work since `osw.close()` would still delegate the close call to `System.out` - just as `bw.close()` would delegate it to `osw` and hence the latter call is unnecessary.